# Codescent objects in Morita 2-category?

Tags: higher-category-theory, 2-categories

Let $\mathbf{Bimod}$ be the 2-category of algebras, bimodules and bimodules maps over a field $\mathbb{k}$. Does this 2-category have codescent objects (see my attempt at giving a definition below)?

Hopefully, the answer is yes! In that case, is it true that the full sub-2-category of $\mathbf{Bimod}$ on the finite algebras and finite bimodules is closed under codescent objects?

Finally, if $\mathbb{k}$ is nice enough, say it is algebraically closed and $char(\mathbb{k})=0$, is the full sub-2-category on the finite semisimple algebras and finite semisimple bimodules closed under codescent objects?

Here is a codescent object: Let $\mathscr{X}$ be the 2-category given by

[image: Codescent diagram]

with invertible 2-cells:
$$\sigma_{i,j}:\delta_i\delta_j \cong \delta_{j-1}\delta_i, i< j$$
$$n_0:\delta_0\iota \cong 1, n_1:1\cong \delta_1\iota.$$

We consider the contravariant 2-functor $J:\mathscr{X}\rightarrow \mathbf{Cat}$ for which $J(X_0)= *$ (the terminal category), $J(X_1) = \{0\cong 1\}$, $J(X_2)=\{0\cong 1\cong 2\}$, the image of $\delta_i:X_1\rightarrow X_0$ under $J$ is the functor $*\mapsto i$, the image of $\delta_i:X_2\rightarrow X_1$ under $J$ is the functor having as image in $J(X_2)$ the arrow $0\cong 1$, $0\cong 2$, $1\cong 2$ for $i=0,1,2$ respectively, and the 2-cells in $\mathscr{X}$ are sent to identity 2-cells in $\mathbf{Cat}$.

Now, a codescent object is a weighted colimit for a covariant 2-functor out of $\mathscr{X}$ with weight $J$.

Comment: I think you should I’m life the definition of codescent objects in the question if you want people to answer it.

Comment: *should include* the definition